# Convert Sorted Array to Balanced 2-3-4 B tree

Tags: data-structures

Given an array where elements are sorted in ascending order,and I need convert it to a [2-3-4 tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-4_tree)

I thought of a recursion which create every loop n/3 nodes, choosing the maximum, and now I'm  having hard time in understanding how to conitinue, It doesn't seem to work this way.

Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you showed what code you have so far, and exactly where you're having trouble.

Comment: I didn't write a code, I still don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an empty almost full tree, and then fill the tree with the array in an inorder search on the empty tree

Comment: How much nodes should I have in this tree?

Comment: @Nir: you need to find the smallest k such that `Sigma((4^i)*3) >= n` for every i in [0,k]. (where n is the array`s size) the solution for this equation will give you the tree`s `height`. Now, according to `Sigma((4^i)*3) - n` you can find out how many 'slots' should be left free for the deepest nodes.